# Firebase security- Do you need all data on every set when you 'validate children on Firebase?

Tags: firebase

If you look at the fredRef example on https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html (bottom of the page):

They say that the first fredRef.set() will fail because it doesn't have a 'last' child. Then they set a first and last, and say it will succeed.

So my question is this:

Would performing the exact same line as the first fredRef.set() AFTER the second fredRef.set() succeed or fail because the set itself doesn't have all of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you would not be able to write to the data at any point unless the data you are writing contains both first/last keys.

However, this is probably not perfectly clear as there appears to be a slight bug in the doc. The way the security rule is written is as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "name": {
    // existing data must have first/last keys before write is allowed
    // since validate rule is not applied to delete ops, this record can be deleted
    ".validate": "data.hasChildren(['first', 'last'])"
    "first": { ... }
    "last": { ... }
    // no keys other than first/last may be written
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

In which case, if you could somehow get a first and last name into the record (say as an admin), any write after this would be allowed, whether it had first/last or not. However, this looks like a typo. Instead of referring to the [data variable](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/data.html)--which references *existing* data, I think this was meant to refer to [newData variable](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/newdata.html), or the data being *written*, like this:

```
// data to be written must have first/last keys before write is allowed
// since validate rule is not applied to delete ops, this record can be deleted
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first', 'last'])"
```

At this point, newData (what you write to that path) must have a first/last name. This also assumes that there is a ".write" rule somewhere in the hierarchy which allows write access.

That rule is a bit higher up in the tutorial:

```
// any authenticated user can write to their own record
".write": "$user == auth.username",
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a typo at all. That in combination with the "$other" rule mean that the question that I posted initially would succeed, because it's not looking at newData, but rather data (a point that I missed initially). The "$other" rule eliminates the possibility of putting junk data into it (which isn't in the example, and should be), but allows updates to the either the first or last name without updating both, which is what I wanted to know.

Comment: Correct, but by looking at data, it would never allow you to write a record in the first place (unless it was written by some admin process); you literally can't write a record unless it already has first/last.

Comment: I figured out the proper syntax to allow updates of individual items and creation of the item itself.. `".validate": "data.hasChildren(['action'])||newData.hasChildren(['action'])",` It would be nice if this had a method to eliminate the boilerplate of essentially the same function twice.